# Cant make calls with Ubuntu Touch RTM v5

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Just got the RTM OS build number 5 today....

Ubuntu Touch has been working great since the RTM up until v5.

Now when I open the phone app, I am presented with "SIM Locked" in the upper left.
If I try to dial and call it says "SIM Card is locked".

I went to "Security & Privacy" in settings. and "SIM PIN" is Off.
For kicks, I tried locking it. Then unlocking it. Rebooting phone, etc.

Nothing fixes it...

What happened with v5?

Any Ideas how to fix this?

I would like to stick with ubuntu touch, but I will have to go back to android soon if I cant call or text.

I have an LGE Nexus 4

UPDATE....

Manually reflashed version 4, which made calling work again. I suppose I'll wait for revision 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's caused by https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/telepathy-ofono/+bug/1379836

You can reflash to an earlier image (RTM #4), manually revert the telepathy-ofono package (see comment #6 in the LP bug link), or manually restart the ofono service (comment #11 in the link)

Comment: After reflashing version 4 I once again tried the update to version 5 and it worked. I'll accept you answer anyway.

Answer (score 3):

From ubuntu touch terminal type this

```
sudo restart ofono
```

Comment: And suddenly it's a phone.  Installed the Terminal app, ran that command and the calls worked. Thanks!